# Dynamic assembly loading in WP7/8

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want my mobile application to update by itself,
Is it possible to dynamically load dlls in Windows Phone applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't possible. The only assemblies you can load are the system assemblies and the ones enclosed in your XAP. Precisely to avoid the scenario you're describing (there would be no point in putting a marketplace certification process if applications could bypass it).